# Скролл плавающей шапки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Шапка сайта плавающая (`postion: fixed; widht: 100%;`). Когда заходишь с телефона, и открываешь какое-нибудь подменю, то список падает ниже экрана.

Поставил `height: 100%` и `overflow: auto;` Но теперь `border-bottom` у `Header` упал в низ экрана. Как исправить?

Comment: кому поставили height: 100% и почему не max-height?

Comment: попробуйте добавить `top: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: @xAqweRx, height: 100% выставил блоку header, чтобы при открытии меню оно листало вверх вниз

Comment: Лучше добавить код css && html cюда.  потому-как сейчас это гадание на кофейной гуще +  было бы не плохо указать на каком телефоне это происходит. Или на всех?

Comment: @xAqweRx, спасибо, попробовал указать max-height, теперь подчеркивание вместе с header и работает прокрутка нормально)

Comment: Код решил не добавлять, потому что сайт на вордпресе, везде классы и айди, думал в описание достаточно предоставил информации, но в следующий раз буду иметь в виду.

Answer (score 1):

Установи блоку следующее:

```
 top: 0; left: 0;
```